# JMeter Proxy on HTTPS doesn't work

Tags: https, proxy, jmeter

I am just working on proxy server load test. I running the JMeter with properties `jmeter -H <my proxy domain> -P <my proxy port>`. The proxy will work if we override the User-Agent with our custom User-Agent, and i am using HTTP Header Manager to do the job.

The problem is, it's worked if i am hit into HTTP protocol, but the JMeter won't override the user-agent if i hit into HTTPS Protocol. Am i missing something ?

I am already checking the proxy via browser, and it's working fine.

Thanks

Comment: uh, that's weird... the only thing that comes into my mind - the scope of the header manager, could you please show how your plan looks like?